# i get this error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out, when connecting to my azure portal mysql database from remote server

Tags: php, mysql, azure

When i try to connect to my azure portal mysql server from my webpage on a remote server i get this error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out. I do not get this error when i host my webpage locally with wamp.

connectionstring:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST .';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8mb4', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    showDbError('connect', $e->getMessage());
}
```

Can anyone help me? (the remote server is the server of my university where alot of webapps are hosted and where i haven't hosted a single mysql webapp yet)

Comment: Are you using ClearDB on Azure as your MySQL provider? And could you please double check that your remote server have enabled the outbound rule for 3306 port?

Comment: I have contacted the firewall of my university and discoverd that the port is blocked, thanks for the reply.